# Selecting from two queries one is normal select the second select is grouped by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C78F.png)I want to get data from two tables, the first one I will collect all the data by select statement, the second I want to group by product_sn and collect the data with while loop. I have tried to combine the loop had no luck, just take a look at the code below and the result that I want below it. After selection I want to pass to JSON to render you can see the code commented out.

The PHP code

```php
<?php

 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
 ini_set('log_errors',1); // well to be 100% sure it will be logged
 
  //######################################### collecting prices start ##################################
  //collect vendor and prices 
  $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'garage');
  //select vendor and price put it inside array
  $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(vendor) as grpd_vendors, GROUP_CONCAT(price_exclvat) as grpd_exclvat, GROUP_CONCAT(price_inclvat) as grpd_inclvat FROM vendor_stock_saved GROUP BY product_sn ORDER BY vendor";
  $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
 
 

 //######################################### collecting prices END ##################################


// db settings
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'garage';

// db connection
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

// fetch records
$sql = "select id, itemcode, sdesc, sbrand, rprice, vendor, costExclTax, costInclTax, qtyonhand from stock";


$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    //  array_push($cvendors, $row["grpd_vendors"]);
    //  array_push($cpriceexclvat, $row["grpd_exclvat"]);
    //  array_push($cpriceinclvat, $row["grpd_inclvat"]);

    //  //convert array to string for data insertion
    // $cvendorsstr = implode(" / ", $cvendors);
    // $cpriceexclvatstr = implode(" / ", $cpriceexclvat);
    // $cpriceinclvatstr = implode(" / ", $cpriceinclvat);

    // ######################################### collecting prices END ##################################
    $grpd_vendors = $row["grpd_vendors"]; //from top query result2
    $grpd_exclvat = $row["grpd_exclvat"]; //from top query result2
    $grpd_inclvat = $row["grpd_inclvat"]; //from top query result2
    
 }





// Update Button
$updateButton = "<button class='btn btn-sm btn-info' data-id='".$row['id']."' style='float: right !important; background: #5E72E4;' ><i class='fa fa-pencil' style='margin-right: 5px;'></i> EDIT </button>";

$exclprices = "<strong>EXCL.TAX: </strong>". $grpd_exclvat;

$inclprices = "<strong>INCL.TAX: </strong>". $grpd_inclvat;

$combinedprices = $exclprices ."<br/>". $inclprices;

$action = $updateButton;

echo "Stock Desc: ".$row['sdesc']."<br/>";
echo "Stock Brand: ".$row['sbrand']."<br/>";
echo "Retail Price: ".$row['rprice']."<br/>";
echo "Vendor: ".$grpd_vendors."<br/>"; //from top query result2
echo "Combined Prices: ". $combinedprices."<br/>"; // combined from top query result2
echo "Qty on hand: ".$row['qtyonhand']."<br/>";
echo "Action:". $action."<br/>";
echo "<br/><br/>";

// $array[] = array(
//     "sdesc" => $row['sdesc'],
//     "sbrand" => $row['sbrand'],
//     "rprice" => $row['rprice'],
//     "vendor" => $cvendorsstr,
//     "combinedprices" => $combinedprices,
//     "qtyonhand" => $row['qtyonhand'],//qtyonhand
//     "action" => $action,
// );

}
// $dataset = array(
//     "echo" => 1,
//     "totalrecords" => count($array),
//     "totaldisplayrecords" => count($array),
//     "data" => $array
// );
// echo json_encode($dataset);

?>
```

[data schema of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C78F.png)

Comment: Where is the problem - on MySQL (you cannot build the query) or on PHP (you cannot process the output)?

Comment: Provide: 1. Table structure(s), 2. Sample content of the tables, 3. The raw queries you have tested with, along with their results, explain whether it was executed correctly and if not, what was the mistake,  4. The issues you had while testing your PHP code. It would not hurt if you tried to reduce your problem-space as well to a minimal reproducible example. Dumping a PHP code that tries to run a MySQL query without providing any useful information about your database and your problem will unlikely yield useful answers.

Comment: `or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con))` is incorrect. You can remove it.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: `I think you can understand there`...not without seeing sample data and schema information, no. Can _you_ write queries on invisible databases?? This is primarily a SQL question...as far as I can see the PHP is not really relevant - all it's doing is just outputting the rows from the query without altering them.

Comment: Hi ADyson correct, I have uploaded an image with the sample data and schema as a phpadmin image I think you will get the idea there...click on data schema of the tables